# Resample (unsampling) yields unpredictable errors on Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a one year multivariate time-serie. A measure for each hour. I want to un-sample the whole data set for each 15 minutes and interpolate values somehow; So I could join it with another data frame using time index.

Following the official documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html), in Google's Colab environment, things are messy. take a look,

[image]

Bellow is the original data frame, above is the re-sampled one. I don't know what are new values coming from.

Comment: Do you use some aggregate function, like `.resample('15Min').mean()` ?

Comment: Also if check error, it say same solution.

Comment: not for now, I commented the line `upsampled.interpolate(method='spline', order=2)` which is a separate operation. Just sampling should work according to the documentation. living times in between with empty data points.

Comment: ah now I know, I have duplicates in my index. I will check and be back

Comment: So need first unique indices - by `resample` with aggregtae function and then need `.interpolate` ?

Comment: exactly. otherwise, results would be unpredictable, at least to my understanding and the time I put on this.

Comment: I am confused with your answer, because cannot see your input data. So it cannot be helpful and I cannot say if exist some better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My index contained duplicates, and was a multi-level index. Instead of using pandas parse_date, I just read and reassemble columns into dates, then set it back as an index. take a look

```
import pandas as pd

climat = pd.read_csv('data_export_2019-02-16 (1).csv', delimiter=';', na_values='--')            #, parse_dates=True, index_col = [2,1,0], 
idx = pd.to_datetime(climat.Year.astype(str) + '-' + climat.Month.astype(str) + '-' + climat.Day.astype(str) + ' ' + climat.Hour.astype(str))
climat.set_index(idx, inplace=True)
climat.drop(['Year','Day', 'Month', 'Hour'], axis=1, inplace=True)

climat_ = climat.drop_duplicates()
upsampled = climat_[['TMP','WNDCHILL','DPT','WNDSPD','WNDGUST','HR','PRMSL','VISIBILITY','TCDC']].resample('15Min')
interpolated = upsampled.interpolate(method='spline', order=2)
```

as you can see, I pushed away this: `parse_dates=True, index_col = [2,1,0]`